# Distance Between Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

Generally, my main question is how to compute distance between two vectors. I'm aware of the formula $d=\| v-u\|$ where $v,u$ are two vectors, and $d$ donates the distance between them.

More specifically, how do I answer the following?

> **True or False**: In $M_{n \times n}^{\Bbb R}$ the **distance** of $\left( \begin {matrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 4 \end {matrix} \right)$ from the subspace $W=sp\left \{ \left( \begin {matrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 2  \end{matrix} \right) , \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{matrix} \right) \right\}$ is $\sqrt{151}$.

The inner product in this **finite subspace** is defined as the $<A,B>=tr(B^tA)$ if $A,B$ are matrcies where $^t$ is the transpose opeartor and $<v,u>=\sum v_i*u_i$ if $v,u$ are vectors.

Thanks,

Alan

Comment: Can you compute the distance from $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 1 \\ 4\end{bmatrix}$ to $W = \text{span} \left( \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \\ 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}\right)$ ?

Comment: Should I compute first the distance between the vectors in the span, then from the third vector?

Comment: No. You should project the vector onto the subspace and find the distance between the vector and the projection (as magnitude of difference of vectors).

Comment: I See. Is there a formula for that projection?

Comment: Yes. Check your Linear Algebra textbook.

Comment: The matrix is the sum of generators... Then is in W and the distance is 0...

Comment: @vvnitram nice observation lol

Comment: @CatalinZara thanks I'll look it up.

Answer (score 1):

Minimise $\| x \begin {bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 2  \end{bmatrix} +y \begin {bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2  \end{bmatrix} - \begin {bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 4  \end{bmatrix} \|^2 = (y-1)^2 + (x-1)^2 + (x-1)^2+(2x+2y-4)^2$.

Inspection shows that $x=1, y=1$ minimises this and the minimum value is zero.

Alternatively, taking the derivatives with respect to $x,y$ respectively gives
$12x+8y=20$, $8x+10y=18$, which has the solution $x=1,y=1$.